How do I get the total number of tests performed based on ID and date range with R?
My data looks like this.  Some people may have up to 48 observations spread over 4 years.  I'm looking to get specific totals based on date ranges.
Name <- c("Doe, John","Doe, John","Doe, John", "Doe, Jane", "Doe, Jane","Doe, Jane", "Doe, Jane")
Accession <- c(123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 678, 789)
MRN <-c(55555, 55555, 55555, 66666, 66666, 66666, 66666)
Collected <-c("2022-01-05", "2022-01-06", "2022-01-07", "2022-01-08", "2022-01-09", "2022-01-20", "2022-01-15")
Result <-c("Detected", "Negative", "Detected", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Detected")

CV <- data.frame(Name, Accession, MRN, Collected, Result)

      Name      Accession           MRN      Collected    Result
1   Doe, John     123              55555      2022-01-05   Detected
2   Doe, John     234              55555      2022-01-06   Negative
3   Doe, John     345              55555      2022-01-07   Detected
4   Doe, Jane     456              66666      2022-01-08   Negative
5   Doe, Jane     567              66666      2022-01-09   Negative
6   Doe, Jane     678              66666      2022-01-20   Negative

I would like to tally observations based on MRN that are +/- 1 day and +/- 2 days from any "Collected" date in the dataframe. I would like my output to look like this:
Name                 MRN        +/-1day_Number_of_Tests            +/-2days_Number_of_Tests
Doe, John           55555                3                                      2
Doe, Jane           66666                3                                      2


Can you walk through the expected results a bit more? I see that John has three results within +/- 1 day of Jan 6, but it seems Jane only has one two results within +/- 1 day of Jan 8 or Jan 9. Are those the expected results? I would also expect there to be more results that are within 2 days of a date than within 1 day.

I could also imagine edge cases like a person having more than one observation in a day - what then? What if a person has obs on day 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8 in one month. Is +/-1day_Number_of_Tests 2 (the max "clique" size of adjacent days), or 6 (three pairs of days), or something else?

Hi @JonSpring thank you for your response.  The data is a little strange for sure.  Perhaps I'm thinking about it incorrectly as well.  You are correct with your second comment that it is possible to have multiple observations in a month I want to look at 4 years of data and basically count people that have results for a particular test because I want to evaluate the frequency of repeat testing while also looking at the accuracy of repeat testing (do results stay the same?).  To your first comment yes, John has 3 and Jane has 2 and there will definitely me more that are within 2 days.

The question is somewhat unclear, but based on my interpretation, this solution should work. Additionally, I changed the type of the Collected vector to date.
Name <- c("Doe, John","Doe, John","Doe, John", "Doe, Jane", "Doe, Jane","Doe, Jane", "Doe, Jane")
Accession <- c(123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 678, 789)
MRN <-c(55555, 55555, 55555, 66666, 66666, 66666, 66666)
Collected <- as.Date(c("2022-01-05", "2022-01-06", "2022-01-07", "2022-01-08", "2022-01-09", "2022-01-20", "2022-01-15"), tz = 'America/New_York')
Result <-c("Detected", "Negative", "Detected", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Detected")
CV <- data.frame(Name, Accession, MRN, Collected, Result)

library(tidyverse)

CV %>% 
  group_by(Name, MRN) %>% 
  summarise(
    day_1 = sum(between(Collected, Collected - 1, Collected + 1), na.rm = TRUE),
    day_2 = sum(between(Collected, Collected - 2, Collected + 2), na.rm = TRUE)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()

